# Rings that are generated as an Algebra over a field by an arbitrary amount of algebraic elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebras

In an introduction course in algebra, you learn, that if you take a field $F$ and an element $x$, which is algebraic over $F $, then the smallest generated Ring by $F$ and $x$, mostly called $F[x]$ is already a field. By induction you can see that this also holds true for finitely many elements $x_1, x_2,\cdots ,x_n$, But what if I want to adjoint an arbitrary amount of elements to $F$. Is it still true?
If yes, do you prove it by transfinite induction, or is there a more obvious argument that I'm missing?

Comment: It's worth noting that transfinite induction isn't the generalization of induction you want to use here. Zorn's Lemma is. They are logically equivalent, but Zorn's Lemma is better suited for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a field containing $F$ and let $S \subseteq \Omega$ such that all the elements of $S$ are algebraic over $F$. Let $K=F[S]$, the smallest subring of $\Omega$ containing $F$ and $S$. Take a non-zero $\alpha \in K$. Then $\alpha$ is a polynomial in finitely many elements $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n \in S$. This means that $\alpha \in F[s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n]$, which is a field because the $s_i$ are algebraic. So, $\alpha$ has an inverse in $F[s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n]\subseteq K$.

Answer (score 2):

If $L$ is a field, $K \subseteq L$ a subfield and $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ a familiy of elements of $L$ which are algebric over $K$, then we have
$$
 K[x_i \mid i \in I]
 = \mathrm{span}_K \{ x_{i_1} \dotsm x_{i_n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \in I\}
 = \bigcup_{\substack{J \subseteq I \\ |J| < \infty}} K[x_j \mid j \in J].
 $$
So $K[x_i \mid i \in I]$ is the union of subfields of $L$, such that every two subfields are contained in another one. Because every finite subset of $K[x_i \mid i \in I]$ is therefore contained is a subfield of $L$ it follows that $K[x_i \mid i \in I]$ itself is also a field.

Answer (score 1):

Every $a$ element of an $F$-algebra $A$ generated by an infinite set of algebraic elements $x_i$ is already in the $F$-algebra $A'$ generated by a finite subset of the $x_i$; this is what the $F$-algebra generated by an infinite set means. But you know that $A'$ is a field, so that if $a\neq0$, it has an inverse in $A'$, and *a fortiori* in $A$.